# online accounts won't connect google on kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, online-accounts

On Kubuntu 20.04, the online accounts menu in settings won't let me connect my Google account. About a 1/4th of the time when I click to connect Google, it would load the login screen with a pure white page. The other times, it would allow me to sign in but would stay frozen with the KDE logo on the page where it's supposed to tell me what access I would be granting KDE to my Google account and doesn't proceed. Is this a 20.04 issue? I'm using `kio-gdrive`.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to right click and reload the page, sometimes it wont show the UI or allow us to interact with the UI, but somehow reloading the page works